# How to incorporate an unicode symbol from STIX?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to import the symbol `\leftouterjoin` from STIX. I read in [the documentation](http://ftp.inf.utfsm.cl/pub/tex-archive/fonts/stix/doc/stix.pdf) that this symbol is identified as the Unicode U+27D5. I have seen several examples where a symbol is inserted in the following way:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{joins}{LS2}{stixfk}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\LeftOuterJoin}{\mathbin}{joins}{"FF}
```

However `"FF` do not correspond with the slot of the symbol `\leftouterjoin`. The slot `"FF` defines a different symbol. Is not clear to me how to determine the slot from its Unicode. How can I determine it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work with pdftex the stix package re-arranges the characters into fonts with 256 characters, so *not* in Unicode position.

Just copying the definition from stix.sty (if you do not want the whole package) shows the numbers to use

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{symbols2}      {LS1}{stixfrak} {m} {n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftouterjoin}            {\mathop}   {symbols2}{"11}

\begin{document}

$a \leftouterjoin b$

\end{document}
```

Comment: LS2 doesn't seem useful, besides being wrongly introduced

Comment: @egreg sorry copied too many lines, fixed.

Comment: In found the codes in `stix.dtx`. I do not found the file `stix.sty`.

Comment: @DanielHernández if you have miktex or texlive you should have it (that is `\usepackage{stix}` should work) in my case `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/stix/stix.sty`